# how to fetch data from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So I normalize my database and it seems quite complicated for me to fetch or update records in tables. 
I have 5 tables ( `details`, `country`, `materials`, `vendor_countries`, `vendor_materials`). Actually `"details"` is my main table.

- `country` table have two column (`id`, `name`).
- `materials` table also have two column(`id`, `name`).
- `details` table have personnel information about vendors (`name`, `email`, `phone`, `address`).

A vendor could have multiple countries and materials so I made two more tables `vendor_countries` and `vendor_materials` and their column are (`did`,`cid`), (`did`,`mid`). 
`"did"` is the id of each vendor coming from `details` table and `cid`,`mid` is the country id and material id coming from country and material table.

Now I want to fetch vendors along with their countries and materials.

here is my details table, vendor_countries and vendor_materials tables

[image: details table][image: vendor material][image: vendor country]

so far I made a query which is shown below:

```
select dt.vendor,
       dt.email,
       dt.address,
       c.country,
       m.material,
       c.country
  from country c
       inner join vendor_countries vc on (c.id = vc.cid)
       right join details dt on (dt.id = vc.did)
       left join vendor_materials vm on dt.id = vm.did
       left join material m on vm.mid = m.id
```

and i am getting results like this:

[image: results]

which is not right it should be in 3 rows because "ali" vendor works in 3 countries and 3 materials. I am looking for some smart solution which also not slow down my page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add sample table data for all tables involved, and specify the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve as well.

Comment: With the query you have given and the description of the data, you should be expecting 9 records returned for 'ali'. If this is not what you are expecting, then show us what you are wanting to get.

Comment: i want to get 3 rows of ali. which is {pakistan, ceramic}, {india, iron} and {iran,plastic}

Comment: can you add the table schemas ?

Comment: But how do you know which material goes with which country? you have nothing to make that association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of any response regarding table schema I tried to re-create the tables based upon the descriptions above -prefixing each table with `v_` so I could group the tables in this db and referencing `did` as `vid` ( vendor id ) and populating with what I believed to be the sample data from the question

```
mysql> describe v_country;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


mysql> describe v_details;
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| vendor  | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email   | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| phone   | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


mysql> describe v_materials;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


mysql> describe v_vendor_materials;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| vid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| mid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


mysql> describe v_vendor_countries;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| vid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| mid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+






mysql> select * from v_country;
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | pakistan |
|  2 | India    |
|  3 | Iran     |
+----+----------+


mysql> select * from v_details;
+----+--------+------------------+---------------+-----------+
| id | vendor | email            | phone         | address   |
+----+--------+------------------+---------------+-----------+
|  1 | harris | harris@gmail.com | 0141 236 4523 | nowhere   |
|  2 | Boris  | boris@gmail.com  | 0141 451 7845 | somewhere |
|  3 | Doris  | doris@gmail.com  | 0141 353 7845 | anywhere  |
+----+--------+------------------+---------------+-----------+


mysql> select * from v_materials;
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | ceramic |
|  2 | iron    |
|  3 | plastic |
+----+---------+


mysql> select * from v_vendor_materials;
+----+-----+-----+
| id | vid | mid |
+----+-----+-----+
|  1 |   1 |   1 |
|  2 |   2 |   2 |
|  3 |   3 |   3 |
+----+-----+-----+


mysql> select * from v_vendor_countries;
+----+-----+-----+
| id | vid | mid |
+----+-----+-----+
|  1 |   1 |   1 |
|  2 |   2 |   2 |
|  3 |   3 |   3 |
+----+-----+-----+





mysql> select * from v_details d
          left outer join v_vendor_materials vm on vm.vid=d.id
          left outer join v_vendor_countries vc on vc.vid=d.id
          left outer join v_materials m on m.id=vm.id
          left outer join v_country c on c.id=vc.id;

+----+--------+------------------+---------------+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+---------+------+----------+
| id | vendor | email            | phone         | address   | id   | vid  | mid  | id   | vid  | mid  | id   | name    | id   | name     |
+----+--------+------------------+---------------+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+---------+------+----------+
|  1 | harris | harris@gmail.com | 0141 236 4523 | nowhere   |    1 |    1 |   1  |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 | ceramic |    1 | pakistan |
|  2 | Boris  | boris@gmail.com  | 0141 451 7845 | somewhere |    2 |    2 |   2  |    2 |    2 |    2 |    2 | iron    |    2 | India    |
|  3 | Doris  | doris@gmail.com  | 0141 353 7845 | anywhere  |    3 |    3 |   3  |    3 |    3 |    3 |    3 | plastic |    3 | Iran     |
+----+--------+------------------+---------------+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+---------+------+----------+
```

or, a more selective query

```
select 
    d.`id` as `vid`,
    d.`vendor`,
    d.`email`,
    d.`phone`,
    d.`address`,
    m.`name` as `material`,
    c.`name` as `country`
    from v_details d
    left outer join v_vendor_materials vm on vm.vid=d.id
    left outer join v_vendor_countries vc on vc.vid=d.id
    left outer join v_materials m on m.id=vm.id
    left outer join v_country c on c.id=vc.id;


+-----+--------+------------------+---------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| vid | vendor | email            | phone         | address   | material | country  |
+-----+--------+------------------+---------------+-----------+----------+----------+
|   1 | harris | harris@gmail.com | 0141 236 4523 | nowhere   | ceramic  | pakistan |
|   2 | Boris  | boris@gmail.com  | 0141 451 7845 | somewhere | iron     | India    |
|   3 | Doris  | doris@gmail.com  | 0141 353 7845 | anywhere  | plastic  | Iran     |
+-----+--------+------------------+---------------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: mate, may you tell me how to create that block table `+------+------+` ? sry OOT.

Comment: open the command prompt, type `mysql -u <USER> -p <DBNAME>` - <ENTER>, then `describe <TABLE>;` ~ items within `<>` to be replaced with real values

Comment: thank you very much. i will try it. PS: this is really helpfull for me to draw table structure example in SO

Comment: Example: `mysql -u root -p inventory` <ENTER> ~ leaving the `-p` with no password on the command line means you get prompted for the password after pressing ENTER. In this the database is called `inventory`

Comment: no the problem is i am getting 9 rows of harris vendors. but I want 3 rows, its showing the result for harris like this: {ceramic,pakistan}, {iron,pakistan},{plastic,pakistan} ,{ceramic,india}, {iron,india},{plastic,india} and then 3 rows for iran

Comment: If you could provide sufficient sql to create the tables and populate with data then it would help - the above was guesstimated on the question